# Plotting Quantiles, subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to solve a question on edx which I just can't seem to get right.

Despite the graph showing the system is saying "Did you call plt.show() twice?"

In the output it also shows this:

```
array([<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f86702755c0>,
       <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f867020dbe0>,
       <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f867022c198>],
      dtype=object)
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated. Thanks

- Plot the DataFrame.

  - Clean up the x-axis labels with the function plt.xticks().
  - Set the first argument equal to np.arange(len(sal_quantiles.index)), the
    second argument equal to sal_quantiles.index, and the keyword
    argument rotation = 'vertical'.
  - Show the plot.  Now call the .plot() method with the argument subplots=True to plot the columns on separate axes. Show this plot as well.

---

```
# Plot the data
sal_quantiles.plot()

# Set xticks
plt.xticks(
    np.arange(len(sal_quantiles.index)),
    sal_quantiles.index, 
    rotation='vertical')

# Show the plot
plt.show()

# Plot with subplots
sal_quantiles.plot(subplots=True)
```

---

Based on previous exercise....
Data source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/college-majors/recent-grads.csv

8. Plotting Quantiles of Salary, Part 1

Now you're interested in plotting a few different quantiles of the average 
salary across major categories so that you can compare the different distributions 
of salary. In this exercise you'll prepare your data for matplotlib.

Instructions

The columns median, p25th, and p75th are currently encoded as strings. Convert these 
columns to numerical values. Then, divide the value of each column by 1000 to make the 
scale of the final plot easier to read.

Find the of each of the three columns for each major category. Save this as sal_quantiles

---

```
import pandas as pd

# Convert to numeric and divide by 1000

recent_grads['median'] = pd.to_numeric(recent_grads['median'])/ 1000

recent_grads['p25th'] = pd.to_numeric(recent_grads['p25th'])/ 1000

recent_grads['p75th'] = pd.to_numeric(recent_grads['p75th'])/ 1000



# Select averages by major category

columns = ['median', 'p25th', 'p75th']

sal_quantiles = recent_grads.groupby(['major_category'])['median', 'p25th', 'p75th'].mean()

print(sal_quantiles)
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide with more information like the full code, and the data

Comment: Hi Vinay

This is based on a previous exercise.

The data source is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/college-majors/recent-grads.csv

Comment: Hi Vinay - please see edited post for previous exercise. Cheers

Comment: 'median', 'p25th', 'p75th' these are different in the original csv file. They should be 'Median', 'P25th' and 'P75th'

Answer (score 0):

You need to display the image again, i.e. `plt.show()`, after applying `subplot=True` to pass the assessment.